# Why SVG doesn't appear correctly in Firefox?

Tags: svg

My SVG logo appears fine in Chrome and Safari. It is made in Illustrator (not by me, I don't know the version). But in FF it is looking weird. Can't find out the reason. I do not use any filters, just SVG image. I've noticed, if I implement it with 'img' tag it looks fine, but becomes too little. Here's the code:

```html
<span>
 <a href="#">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="190px" height="42px" viewBox="93.496 77.153 190 42"
       overflow="visible" enable-background="new 93.496 77.153 190 42" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs></defs>
    <g>
      <defs>
        <path class="logotype" id="SVGID_2_" d="M125.99,85.758c-0.725-0.005-1.443-0.016-2.154-0.034c0.072-1.776,0.818-3.368,2.002-4.549
          c1.244-1.236,2.953-2,4.854-2c1.898,0,3.609,0.764,4.854,2c1.102,1.1,1.829,2.561,1.978,4.193
          c-3.235,0.256-6.702,0.396-10.312,0.396C126.806,85.765,126.398,85.762,125.99,85.758 M124.41,79.744
          c-1.531,1.522-2.508,3.611-2.596,5.918c-4.139-0.158-8.042-0.497-11.571-0.982l-1.538,7.253c5.02,0.72,10.882,1.135,17.144,1.135
          c1.814,0,3.595-0.036,5.331-0.104l4.226,21.692c9.233,0.162,17.411,1.503,22.897,3.531l-6.656-35.073
          c-3.283,0.903-7.416,1.617-12.107,2.078c-0.195-2.121-1.139-4.029-2.566-5.447c-1.605-1.602-3.832-2.591-6.281-2.591
          S126.014,78.142,124.41,79.744"/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="SVGID_3_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_2_"  overflow="visible"/>
      </clipPath>
      <rect x="102.238" y="77.153" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#C80711" width="59.287" height="52.211"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M137.781,150.214l-13.065-12.074l-13.067,12.074l1.295-17.745l-17.588-2.688
        l14.68-10.052l-8.865-15.427l17.012,5.211l6.534-16.55l6.534,16.55l17.013-5.211l-8.866,15.427l14.682,10.052l-17.59,2.688
        L137.781,150.214z M124.716,133.246l8.821,8.153l-0.873-11.981l11.873-1.812l-9.912-6.787l5.986-10.414l-11.484,3.517
        l-4.411-11.171l-4.411,11.171l-11.485-3.517l5.986,10.414l-9.911,6.787l11.873,1.812l-0.873,11.981L124.716,133.246z"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M146.598,169.522l-21.882-20.223l-21.88,20.223l2.166-29.714l-29.449-4.5
        l24.58-16.832L85.289,92.644l28.487,8.724l10.939-27.71l10.939,27.71l28.488-8.724l-14.846,25.832l24.583,16.832l-29.451,4.5
        L146.598,169.522z M124.716,144.407l17.634,16.298l-1.746-23.947l23.736-3.627l-19.812-13.566l11.965-20.818l-22.958,7.032
        l-8.818-22.334l-8.817,22.334L92.94,98.746l11.964,20.818L85.092,133.13l23.736,3.627l-1.746,23.947L124.716,144.407z"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M94.051,188.764l3.037-41.644l-41.273-6.305l34.45-23.59L69.461,81.023
        l39.923,12.227l15.332-38.834l15.333,38.834l39.924-12.225l-20.805,36.201l34.451,23.59l-41.275,6.305l3.037,41.644l-30.665-28.338
        L94.051,188.764z M124.716,155.534l26.419,24.413l-2.615-35.878l35.559-5.431l-29.682-20.324l17.926-31.188L137.925,97.66
        l-13.209-33.461L111.507,97.66L77.111,87.125l17.924,31.188l-29.681,20.324l35.558,5.431l-2.615,35.878L124.716,155.534z"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M85.701,207.058l3.863-52.984l-52.515-8.022l43.834-30.014L54.411,69.977
        l50.796,15.556l19.509-49.412l19.507,49.412l50.798-15.556l-26.472,46.061l43.833,30.014l-52.515,8.022l3.863,52.984
        l-39.015-36.056L85.701,207.058z M124.716,166.11l34.771,32.131l-3.443-47.217l46.8-7.15l-39.064-26.748l23.59-41.046
        l-45.268,13.863l-17.386-44.037L107.33,89.943L62.062,76.078l23.592,41.048l-39.063,26.748l46.799,7.15l-3.442,47.217
        L124.716,166.11z"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M171.932,225.026l-47.216-43.637l-47.217,43.637l4.677-64.124l-63.556-9.708
        l53.048-36.323L39.634,59.128l61.474,18.825l23.608-59.8l23.61,59.8l61.472-18.825l-32.035,55.742l53.046,36.323l-63.552,9.708
        L171.932,225.026z M124.716,176.497l42.971,39.712l-4.254-58.356l57.838-8.837l-48.277-33.056l29.154-50.731l-55.945,17.135
        l-21.487-54.424l-21.487,54.424L47.285,65.228l29.153,50.731l-48.277,33.056L86,157.852l-4.254,58.356L124.716,176.497z"/>
      <path class="logotype" clip-path="url(#SVGID_3_)" fill="#E74200" d="M180.219,243.18l-55.503-51.295L69.212,243.18l5.497-75.378L0,156.389
        l62.357-42.699L24.701,48.164l72.264,22.133L124.716,0l27.753,70.296l72.263-22.131l-37.658,65.524l62.357,42.699l-74.708,11.413
        L180.219,243.18z M124.716,186.994l51.257,47.369l-5.076-69.61l68.994-10.541l-57.587-39.433l34.777-60.514l-66.734,20.438
        l-25.63-64.917l-25.63,64.918L32.352,54.265l34.777,60.514L9.541,154.211l68.993,10.541l-5.075,69.61L124.716,186.994z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <defs>
        <path class="logotype" id="SVGID_1_" d="M98.551,89.699l-4.895,28.619c5.639-1.504,13.049-2.419,21.174-2.419c8.184,0,15.645,0.927,21.295,2.451
          l-4.945-25.388c-1.736,0.068-3.517,0.104-5.331,0.104c-11.22,0-21.155-1.329-27.261-3.368H98.551z"/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
      </clipPath>       
        <rect x="87.936" y="84.597" transform="matrix(1 0.0028 -0.0028 1 0.2934 -0.3189)" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#F8B700" width="53.723" height="41.486"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,93.814c-6.564,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.561
        c-3.082-1.205-5.994-2.344-11.964-2.344c-5.974,0-8.884,1.139-11.965,2.344c-3.219,1.259-6.547,2.561-13.113,2.561
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.561c-3.082-1.205-5.993-2.344-11.964-2.344v-3.151c6.564,0,9.894,1.302,13.111,2.56
        c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345s8.884-1.14,11.966-2.345c3.218-1.258,6.544-2.56,13.112-2.56
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.302,13.111,2.56c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345V93.814z"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,99.516c-6.564,0-9.894-1.301-13.111-2.56
        c-3.082-1.205-5.994-2.344-11.964-2.344c-5.974,0-8.884,1.139-11.965,2.344c-3.219,1.259-6.547,2.56-13.113,2.56
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.301-13.111-2.56c-3.082-1.205-5.993-2.344-11.964-2.344v-3.15c6.564,0,9.894,1.3,13.111,2.559
        c3.082,1.203,5.992,2.344,11.964,2.344s8.884-1.141,11.966-2.344c3.218-1.259,6.544-2.559,13.112-2.559
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.3,13.111,2.559c3.082,1.203,5.992,2.344,11.964,2.344V99.516z"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,105.219c-6.564,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.562
        c-3.082-1.204-5.994-2.343-11.964-2.343c-5.974,0-8.884,1.139-11.965,2.343c-3.219,1.26-6.547,2.562-13.113,2.562
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.562c-3.082-1.204-5.993-2.343-11.964-2.343v-3.151c6.564,0,9.894,1.301,13.111,2.561
        c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.343,11.964,2.343s8.884-1.138,11.966-2.343c3.218-1.26,6.544-2.561,13.112-2.561
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.301,13.111,2.561c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.343,11.964,2.343V105.219z"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,110.921c-6.564,0-9.894-1.301-13.111-2.561
        c-3.082-1.203-5.994-2.343-11.964-2.343c-5.974,0-8.884,1.14-11.965,2.343c-3.219,1.26-6.547,2.561-13.113,2.561
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.301-13.111-2.561c-3.082-1.203-5.993-2.343-11.964-2.343v-3.151c6.564,0,9.894,1.301,13.111,2.56
        c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.343,11.964,2.343s8.884-1.138,11.966-2.343c3.218-1.259,6.544-2.56,13.112-2.56
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.301,13.111,2.56c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.343,11.964,2.343V110.921z"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,116.625c-6.564,0-9.894-1.303-13.111-2.56
        c-3.082-1.207-5.994-2.347-11.964-2.347c-5.974,0-8.884,1.14-11.965,2.347c-3.219,1.257-6.547,2.56-13.113,2.56
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.303-13.111-2.56c-3.082-1.207-5.993-2.347-11.964-2.347v-3.15c6.564,0,9.894,1.303,13.111,2.561
        c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345s8.884-1.14,11.966-2.345c3.218-1.258,6.544-2.561,13.112-2.561
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.303,13.111,2.561c3.082,1.205,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345V116.625z"/>
      <path class="logotype yellow" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#FFD303" d="M147.943,122.328c-6.564,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.561
        c-3.082-1.204-5.994-2.344-11.964-2.344c-5.974,0-8.884,1.14-11.965,2.344c-3.219,1.259-6.547,2.561-13.113,2.561
        c-6.567,0-9.894-1.302-13.111-2.561c-3.082-1.204-5.993-2.344-11.964-2.344v-3.15c6.564,0,9.894,1.3,13.111,2.558
        c3.082,1.206,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345s8.884-1.139,11.966-2.345c3.218-1.258,6.544-2.558,13.112-2.558
        c6.564,0,9.894,1.3,13.111,2.558c3.082,1.206,5.992,2.345,11.964,2.345V122.328z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="logotype" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M104.481,98.085c0.056-1.06,0.961-1.873,2.02-1.818c1.061,0.057,1.874,0.962,1.816,2.021
      c-0.056,1.059-0.963,1.874-2.021,1.816C105.237,100.049,104.425,99.143,104.481,98.085"/>
    <path class="logotype" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M121.512,98.991c0.057-1.06,0.96-1.874,2.021-1.817c1.058,0.057,1.872,0.963,1.816,2.021
      c-0.057,1.06-0.963,1.873-2.02,1.816C122.269,100.955,121.454,100.049,121.512,98.991"/>
    <path class="logotype" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M122.422,100.533c-0.112,2.086-1.057,3.921-2.504,5.219c-1.448,1.294-3.385,2.037-5.483,1.927
      c-2.101-0.112-3.947-1.059-5.25-2.499c-1.302-1.442-2.047-3.367-1.937-5.454l-1.662-0.088c-0.137,2.541,0.779,4.906,2.363,6.659
      c1.583,1.755,3.846,2.909,6.396,3.046c2.551,0.134,4.924-0.774,6.684-2.351c1.762-1.575,2.922-3.829,3.058-6.37L122.422,100.533z"/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="164.267,111.836 169.359,111.836 169.359,112.818 167.371,112.818 167.371,117.895 166.293,117.895 
      166.293,112.818 164.267,112.818 "/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M173.748,111.731c1.877,0,3.238,1.32,3.238,3.131c0,1.783-1.387,3.127-3.238,3.127
      c-1.855,0-3.233-1.337-3.233-3.127C170.515,113.112,171.929,111.731,173.748,111.731 M173.756,117.049
      c1.17,0,2.086-0.938,2.086-2.172c0-1.24-0.871-2.18-2.086-2.18c-1.199,0-2.086,0.939-2.086,2.18
      C171.67,116.093,172.583,117.049,173.756,117.049"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M180.176,116.137v1.757h-1.068v-6.058h1.854c1.611,0,2.422,0.888,2.422,2.155
      c0,1.266-0.803,2.146-2.629,2.146H180.176z M180.176,112.818v2.369h0.707c1.001,0,1.344-0.533,1.344-1.195
      c0-0.664-0.336-1.174-1.344-1.174H180.176z"/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="185.557,111.836 189.494,111.836 189.494,112.818 186.623,112.818 186.623,117.895 185.557,117.895 
      "/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M193.855,111.731c1.879,0,3.24,1.32,3.24,3.131c0,1.783-1.387,3.127-3.24,3.127s-3.23-1.337-3.23-3.127
      C190.625,113.112,192.037,111.731,193.855,111.731 M193.865,117.049c1.174,0,2.084-0.938,2.084-2.172c0-1.24-0.869-2.18-2.084-2.18
      c-1.201,0-2.088,0.939-2.088,2.18C191.777,116.093,192.691,117.049,193.865,117.049"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M199.214,111.836h1.939c1.561,0,2.26,0.646,2.26,1.602c0,0.656-0.381,1.122-1.061,1.363
      c0.836,0.241,1.223,0.73,1.223,1.379c0,1.076-1.043,1.714-2.422,1.714h-1.939V111.836z M200.285,112.818v1.647h0.766
      c0.869,0.008,1.25-0.44,1.25-0.897c0-0.413-0.309-0.75-1.096-0.75H200.285z M200.285,115.231v1.681h0.92
      c0.906,0,1.215-0.396,1.215-0.845c0-0.413-0.344-0.836-1.471-0.836H200.285z"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M207.394,113.592c1.828,0,2.629,0.881,2.629,2.147c0,1.268-0.811,2.153-2.422,2.153h-1.854v-6.057h1.068
      v1.756H207.394z M207.521,116.912c1.008,0,1.346-0.508,1.346-1.172c0-0.663-0.344-1.196-1.346-1.196h-0.705v2.368H207.521z"/>
    <rect x="211.56" y="111.836" fill="#E50004" width="1.068" height="6.057"/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="220.744,117.893 219.675,117.893 219.675,114.137 215.873,117.937 215.589,117.937 215.589,111.836 
      216.658,111.836 216.658,115.706 220.406,111.801 220.744,111.801 "/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="231.878,116.912 231.878,111.836 230.81,111.836 230.81,116.912 228.136,116.912 228.136,111.836 
      227.068,111.836 227.068,117.893 231.414,117.893 231.414,118.552 232.398,118.552 232.482,116.912 "/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="234.394,111.836 238.333,111.836 238.333,112.818 235.462,112.818 235.462,114.516 238.066,114.516 
      238.066,115.463 235.462,115.463 235.462,116.912 238.333,116.912 238.333,117.895 234.394,117.895 "/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="244.634,115.507 241.675,115.507 241.675,117.893 240.607,117.893 240.607,111.836 241.675,111.836 
      241.675,114.559 244.634,114.559 244.634,111.844 245.703,111.844 245.703,117.893 244.634,117.893 "/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="247.449,111.836 252.542,111.836 252.542,112.818 250.554,112.818 250.554,117.895 249.476,117.895 
      249.476,112.818 247.449,112.818 "/>
    <path class="logotype" fill="#E50004" d="M255.361,116.137v1.757h-1.068v-6.058h1.854c1.611,0,2.422,0.888,2.422,2.155
      c0,1.266-0.803,2.146-2.629,2.146H255.361z M255.361,112.818v2.369h0.707c1.002,0,1.346-0.533,1.346-1.195
      c0-0.664-0.336-1.174-1.346-1.174H255.361z"/>
    <polygon fill="#E50004" points="219.472,111.126 217.14,111.426 217.14,110.569 219.472,110.569 "/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M179.885,93.099c-0.427-1.114-1.057-2.094-1.874-2.91c-0.815-0.814-1.829-1.459-3.011-1.918
      c-1.18-0.455-2.529-0.686-4.015-0.686c-1.338,0-2.603,0.251-3.763,0.746c-1.155,0.498-2.18,1.188-3.046,2.051l-0.208,0.211
      c0,0,0.322,1.734,2.021,2.366l0.242-0.243c0.611-0.611,1.334-1.098,2.148-1.446c0.811-0.348,1.694-0.524,2.627-0.524
      c0.996,0,1.88,0.131,2.625,0.395c0.736,0.262,1.365,0.63,1.873,1.098c0.511,0.465,0.921,1.033,1.224,1.682
      c0.228,0.49,0.355,1.18,0.479,1.758c-0.229-0.252-0.679-0.4-1.052-0.453c-0.559-0.076-1.127-0.116-1.686-0.116h-5.823
      c0,0-0.592,1.777,0,3.161h5.823c0.498,0,1.01,0.037,1.514,0.109c0.4,0.061,0.877,0.184,1.129,0.49
      c-0.176,0.579-0.389,0.968-0.734,1.456c-0.4,0.562-0.879,1.055-1.432,1.459c-0.552,0.403-1.174,0.724-1.85,0.947
      c-0.674,0.224-1.385,0.339-2.112,0.339c-1.062,0-2.046-0.23-2.93-0.685c-0.886-0.451-1.646-1.075-2.257-1.856l-0.26-0.329
      c-1.424,0.595-1.938,2.635-1.938,2.635l0.174,0.194c0.895,0.99,1.979,1.779,3.213,2.344c1.236,0.568,2.59,0.856,4.02,0.856
      c1.336,0,2.598-0.248,3.75-0.737c1.148-0.487,2.162-1.164,3.014-2.017s1.529-1.87,2.018-3.026c0.488-1.16,0.736-2.418,0.736-3.736
      C180.525,95.421,180.31,94.208,179.885,93.099"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M200.203,93.099c0.428-1.114,1.059-2.094,1.873-2.91c0.816-0.814,1.83-1.459,3.014-1.918
      c1.178-0.455,2.529-0.686,4.014-0.686c1.338,0,2.605,0.251,3.764,0.746c1.154,0.498,2.178,1.188,3.045,2.051l0.207,0.211
      c0,0-0.32,1.734-2.02,2.366l-0.242-0.243c-0.611-0.611-1.338-1.098-2.148-1.446c-0.811-0.348-1.697-0.524-2.625-0.524
      c-1,0-1.881,0.131-2.627,0.395c-0.734,0.262-1.365,0.63-1.873,1.098c-0.512,0.465-0.922,1.033-1.223,1.682
      c-0.23,0.49-0.355,1.18-0.482,1.758c0.23-0.252,0.682-0.4,1.055-0.453c0.559-0.076,1.125-0.116,1.684-0.116h5.824
      c0,0,0.592,1.777,0,3.161h-5.824c-0.498,0-1.008,0.037-1.514,0.109c-0.402,0.061-0.875,0.184-1.129,0.49
      c0.176,0.579,0.391,0.968,0.734,1.456c0.4,0.562,0.881,1.055,1.432,1.459c0.553,0.403,1.174,0.724,1.852,0.947
      c0.674,0.224,1.385,0.339,2.111,0.339c1.062,0,2.047-0.23,2.93-0.685c0.889-0.451,1.646-1.075,2.256-1.856l0.26-0.329
      c1.424,0.595,1.939,2.635,1.939,2.635l-0.174,0.194c-0.896,0.99-1.977,1.779-3.211,2.344c-1.24,0.568-2.592,0.856-4.02,0.856
      c-1.338,0-2.602-0.248-3.752-0.737c-1.148-0.487-2.162-1.164-3.016-2.017c-0.85-0.853-1.527-1.87-2.016-3.026
      c-0.488-1.16-0.736-2.418-0.736-3.736C199.564,95.421,199.781,94.208,200.203,93.099"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M235.472,91.248h6.102v14.592c0,0,1.51,0.681,3.068,0V91.248h6.031c0.674-1.414,0-3.158,0-3.158h-15.201
      C235.472,88.089,234.785,89.76,235.472,91.248"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M267.292,95.464c0.252-0.641,0.381-1.37,0.381-2.171c0-0.802-0.129-1.53-0.381-2.17
      c-0.252-0.644-0.617-1.2-1.086-1.651c-0.467-0.447-1.039-0.797-1.701-1.032c-0.652-0.231-1.377-0.351-2.16-0.351h-9.121v17.75
      c0,0,1.492,0.717,3.139,0v-6.707c0.436-0.21,0.887-0.355,1.344-0.433c0.529-0.089,1.066-0.132,1.602-0.132h3.033
      c0.789,0,1.516-0.123,2.168-0.365c0.662-0.244,1.234-0.605,1.703-1.071C266.675,96.666,267.041,96.105,267.292,95.464
       M262.33,91.248c0.748,0,1.312,0.154,1.678,0.456c0.35,0.286,0.527,0.821,0.527,1.59c0,1.442-0.701,2.114-2.203,2.114h-3.027
      c-0.572,0-1.146,0.037-1.707,0.115c-0.416,0.062-0.828,0.182-1.229,0.365l-0.006-4.641H262.33z"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M274.802,88.105h-1.17l-8.762,17.734c0,0,1.758,0.664,3.404,0l0.529-0.979
      c0.047-0.096,1.137-1.521,3.656-1.521h6.246l1.123,2.501c1.346,0.591,3.506,0,3.506,0L274.802,88.105z M277.265,100.177h-3.289
      c-1.996,0-2.592,0.282-3.018,0.536l3.105-6.72L277.265,100.177z"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M186.615,88.089l-0.271,2.808c-0.088,0.845-0.197,1.722-0.318,2.601c-0.121,0.858-0.283,1.71-0.477,2.533
      c-0.195,0.822-0.445,1.628-0.744,2.396c-0.297,0.768-0.847,1.761-1.291,2.467c-0.31,0.487-0.598,0.873-0.855,1.145
      c-0.256,0.268-0.492,0.469-0.713,0.596c-0.211,0.126-0.406,0.206-0.579,0.238c-0.202,0.033-0.39,0.052-0.565,0.052h-0.008
      c0,0-0.85,1.702,0,3.16h0.008c0.237,0,0.521-0.016,0.844-0.048c0.337-0.033,0.692-0.107,1.06-0.221
      c0.374-0.109,0.758-0.285,1.138-0.511c0.387-0.23,0.752-0.547,1.079-0.941c0.703-0.842,1.308-1.802,1.8-2.856
      c0.486-1.046,1.075-2.401,1.404-3.547c0.329-1.145,0.6-2.33,0.8-3.525c0.182-1.082,0.327-2.15,0.434-3.187h4.325v14.591
      c0,0,1.777,0.57,3.137,0v-17.75H186.615z"/>
    <path class="logotype red" fill="#E50004" d="M228.027,96.486h0.01l-0.008-0.005l0.008-0.008h-0.01l-0.006-0.009l5.844-8.374c0,0-2.352-0.743-3.783,0
      l-4.348,6.416h-2.32c-0.965,0-1.328,0.256-1.541,0.474v-6.936c0,0-1.572-0.759-3.137,0v17.762c1.564,0.758,3.137,0,3.137,0V98.16
      c0.193-0.23,0.469-0.553,1.545-0.553h1.85l4.814,8.153c1.432,0.741,3.783,0,3.783,0l-5.844-9.263L228.027,96.486z"/>
  </svg>
 </a>
</span>
```

Finally I implemented it through `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img src="app/svg-icons/logo.svg" alt="logo" height="87px" width="200px" />
```

But it would be interesting, why it doesn't work with inline implementation.

Comment: In Firefox: http://joxi.ru/Q2KYKe1u9D1pOr
In Chrome: http://joxi.ru/8AnoPzbiqLeEnr

Comment: works fine in Firefox for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other embedded SVGs on the page?  If so then read on.

Perhaps the most common cause for problems like this is that you are including multiple SVG images on the page which have clashing `id` attributes.  This can easily happen if you have made the SVGs in an editor like Illustrator, which reuses the same ids for every image it creates.

If you look at the SVG contents, you'll see that the ids in there are "SVGID_1_", "SVGID_2_", "SVGID_3_", etc.

`id` attributes in an HTML must be unique.  How duplicate ids are handled can vary from browser to browser, which is why you are getting different results in FF and Chrome.

The fix is to (manually) edit each `id` value to make them unique.  Don't forget to edit any references to them as well (eg.: the entries like `xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"`).